# ngMap directive not displaying the location coordinates taken from service file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-view

I am trying to call location coordinates from service file and display in google map view. But for some reason the data binding is not working, and there are no errors and the controller is calling the object from service.

I think there is some mistake in my map template, but I'm not able to find out what it is. Can some please help me with this issue? Thank you.

The codes are as follows:

**map template**

```
<div class="panel6 panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Truck's Location</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ng-map zoom="11" center="[49.8994, -97.1392]">
            <marker position="[{{maploc.longitude}}, {{maploc.latitude}}]" />
            <shape name="circle" center="[{{maploc.longitude}}, {{maploc.latitude}}]" radius="4000" />
            <control name="overviewMap" opened="true" />
        </ng-map>
        </div>
   </div>
```

---

**service file**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetListModule").service("fleetsService",

       function () {
           this.getTrucks = function () {
               return trucks;
           };

           var trucks = [
               {
                   "iD": "1",
                   "status": "Running",
                   "destination": "WPG",
                   "alerts": "Nothing",
                       "longitude": "49.8994",
                       "latitude": "-98.1392"
               }
           ];

       });
```

---

**controller**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetMapModule").controller("fleetMapController",
    ['$scope', 'fleetsService',
function ($scope, fleetsService) {

    $scope.$on('obtainMapLocation', function (event, map) {
        var fleetMapLocs = fleetsService.getTrucks();
        for (var i = 0; i < fleetMapLocs.length; i++) {
            var fleetMapLoc = fleetMapLocs[i];
            if (fleetMapLoc.iD == map.id) {
                $scope.maploc = fleetMapLoc;
                break;

            }
        }
    });

}]);
```

Comment: remove [] brackets in position. look how it is done here https://ngmap.github.io/#/!marker-simple.html

Comment: removing the square brackets is not working to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSJOQjDrr1fI05QwS09d) it is working. And if you set default values for $scope.maploc you will see marker. But the problem is in **if** statement that is always false.

```
if (fleetMapLoc.iD == map.id)
```

Comment: Ok. got it. Thank you.

Comment: np. I have no idea whats doing on inside rest of your code. And why do you have multiple maps IDs. If you can provide more info i will check it out later.

Comment: Oh those are truck ids. I wanted to track the trucks location based on their ids. Its working now, its just that I had to bind the "center" to in the template. Thanks again.